# How to call a method that comes from the service ViewController A delegated for in a button of ViewController B?

Tags: swift, multipeer-connectivity

I have implemented `ViewControllerA`, which is also a delegate of a service(multipeer connectivity basically) implemented. 
I have a View `Controller B`, where there are some user interaction and a button called "Send".
In the action of this button, I hope it will called a method that could only be executed from ViewController A, which is a method from the service A delegate for. 
May I know if there's any good way I would achieve this? I am new to Swift. If there's better way to design it, I would like to know too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to use `Delegate` From `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB`. Means ViewControllerB will create a protocol and delegate property. ViewControllerA will conform the protocol methods and will implement required and optional(can do) method. On the action of ViewControllerB send you will actually call the protocol method using delegate property. Which will invoke ViewControllerA implemented method where you can invoke any method.

**Protocol:**

```
protocol ViewControllerBDelegate: class {
  func didSendClicked(sender: UIbutton)
}
```

**Delegate property:**

```
@property (weak) id<ViewControllerBDelegate> delegate;
```

**Conforming Protocol by ViewControllerA:**

```
@interface ViewControllerA () <ViewControllerBDelegate>
@end
```

**Implement the method in viewControllerA:**

```
- (void)didSendClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
  // do stuff 
}
```

**Settings delegtae for viewControllerA**

```
viewControllerB.delegate = viewControllerA(ref)
```

**Invoking delegate method from viewControllerB**

```
delegate?.didSendClicked(self)
```

**Solution: 2**
you can use `NSNotificationCenter` for same callback.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it out. Would it be ok to have A as someService's delegate and B as A's delegate?

Comment: it depends, upon the situation some times delegate then sometimes postnotifcation works.